# How can I define a constant that includes a space in my .env file?

Tags: laravel-5

New to Laravel (love it though), so I apologize in advance. I am coming from CodeIgniter land, so it's quite possible I'm trying to bring over some bad habits.

I am defining a constant in my .env file to keep all of my email & names in one spot. In this case, I am storing my general email information:

**.env**

```
NOREPLY_EMAIL=noreply@mysite.com
CONTACT_EMAIL=contact@mysite.com
CONTACT_NAME=Bill Brasky
```

Then in my controller, I am accessing this like this:

**MyController.php**

```
 Mail::send('emails.template', array('key' => 'value'), function ($message) {
     $message->from(env('NOREPLY_EMAIL'), 'My Site');
     $message->to(env('CONTACT_EMAIL'), env('CONTACT_NAME'))->subject('My Subject');
});
```

Everything works great until I put the `CONTACT_NAME` in my .env file. I get this error:

```
Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class log does not exist'
```

I remove the `CONTACT_NAME` constant and all is well again. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the value in quotes

```
CONTACT_NAME="Bill Brasky"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I (guess) I assumed everything was a string so I didn't think about that. Do I need/would you suggest I wrap things like email addresses etc. in quotes as well?